# Alternative to relying on execution order of conditions in SQL 'where' clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

In languages such as JavaScript you can have 2 conditional statements and "protect" the second one with the first one. For instance:

```
if( scarryObject != null && scarryObject.scarryMethod() ) { ... }
// if scarryObject is null scarryMethod will not be called
```

I thought I would achieve the same in SQL like so:

```
where int_date > 19500101
    and month(CONVERT(smalldatetime, ... int_date))
```

The problem here is that if `int_date` is some "bad" value like -1, 0, 1 the conversion will fail and the sp will stop with an error. I thought the first check `int_date > 19500101` would get evaluated first and if false the second condition would be skipped.

It seems like it does not work like this... or? Is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your query is syntactically not correct, as the clause`month(CONVERT....` is not a condition.

Let's assume you want to compare with a certain number, a possible way of expressing what you want would be

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable
WHERE  case 
       when int_date > 19500101 
         then -1 
         else month(CONVERT(smalldatetime, ... int_date))
       end = @YourMonth
```

You would 'protect' the evaluation of the 'month' and not the condition.

Answer (score -1):

You could try splitting the query into two. Here is the concept:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE int_date > 19500101
) t
WHERE month(CONVERT(smalldatetime, ... t.int_date))
```